# In Javascript if else statement, only if is executed even if its not true

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to make this code run. In the function GradeCal(), Only the if statement is executed even if the condition is not true. For some reason the else is not being executed. Dont know what I am doing wrong. P.S I am a beginner in JS. 
Here is my code

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>It430
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <h2>Grade Book Calculator</h2>
    <h4> Welcome to Grade Book Calculator </h4>
    <form id="my form">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Student ID:</td>
          <td> <input id="studentid" value="bc180200783" oninvalid="alert(Please Enter Student ID)" type="text" place holder="Enter your VU ID" required="required" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Name:</td>
          <td> <input id="nameid" value="Hina" oninvalid="alert(Please Enter Name)" type="text" required="required" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Father Name:</td>
          <td> <input id="fathernameid" value="Zafar" oninvalid="alert(Please Enter Father Name)" type="text" required="required" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>CNIC:</td>
          <td> <input id="cnicid" pattern="^[0-9+][5]-[0-9+][7]-[0-9][1]$" value="33100-1100321-5" oninvalid="alert(Please Enter CNIC)" required="required" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>English:</td>
          <td> <input id="englishid" oninvalid="alert(Please Enter English Marks)" name="english" required="required" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Math:</td>
          <td> <input id="mathid" oninvalid="alert(Please Enter Math Marks)" name="math" required="required" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Computer:</td>
          <td> <input id="computerid" oninvalid="alert(Please Enter Computer Marks)" name="computer" required="required" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Average Marks:</td>
          <td> <output type="number" id="markid"> </output>
          </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
          <td> <button type="button" onClick="GradeCal()"> Grade Book </button>
            <button type="reset"> Reset</button></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </center>
  <script>
    function GradeCal() {
      var field1 = document.getElementById("englishid");
      var field2 = document.getElementById("mathid");
      var field3 = document.getElementById("computerid");
      var result;

      if (field1 || field2 || field3 === NULL) {
        alert("Please enter number");
      } else {
        result = (parseFloat(field1) + parseFloat(field2) + parseFloat(field3)) / 3;
        document.getElementById("markid").innerHTML = +result;
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `(field1 || field2 || field3 === NULL)` doesn't check if any one of them === NULL ... for one thing, `NULL` is not defined (did you mean `null`) and another it's `if (filed1 === null || field2 === null || field3 === null)` ... because `||` doesn't work like you think

Comment: And `field1` is the element, not the value in it. So, it will never be null

Comment: Also, `NULL` !== `null`.

Comment: what are you trying to do ? That statement will always be true if one of the elements exists or the last one is NULL

Comment: Also, `null` is never the value of an `input`.

Comment: i want that if any of the field is empty, it should display an alert Please enter number

Comment: then how do i compare my fields  to empty or no value ?

Comment: `if (field1 || field2 || field3 === NULL)` => `if (!field1 || !field2 || !field3)`

Answer (score 2):

You are not accessing the value of the elements. You should change your code to include extracting the values from the HTML elements. Like so:

```
var field1 = document.getElementById("englishid").value;
var field2 = document.getElementById("mathid").value;
var field3 = document.getElementById("computerid").value;
```

The `.value` will extract the value in the HTML tag.

You can also improve your if statement. The following might not be doing what you think it does:

```
if (field1 || field2 || field3 === NULL)
```

What actually happens here it that it say's: `Is field1 set (not NULL, undefined, 0, NaN, "" or false) OR is field2 set (not NULL, undefined, 0, NaN, "" or false) OR is field3 NULL.`

If you want to check if any of them is null you will need to do something like:

```
 if (field1 === NULL || field2 === NULL || field3 === NULL)
```

Or even better and more easy:

```
if (!field1 || !field2 || !field3)
```

The full function:

```
function GradeCal() {
      var field1 = document.getElementById("englishid").value;
      var field2 = document.getElementById("mathid").value;
      var field3 = document.getElementById("computerid").value;
      var result;

      if (!field1 || !field2 || !field3) {
        alert("Please enter number");
      } else {
        result = (field1 + field2 + field3) / 3;
        document.getElementById("markid").innerHTML = +result;
      }
    }
```

Comment: if use this, then it just executes the if statement and always displays the alert message, even if i have entered all the inputs. it doesnt calculate the average.

Comment: `(not NULL or undefined)` or 0 or NaN or "" or false

Comment: @noora I edited my post to include why you are getting NaN.

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze thanks for the input. I edited the post to include them.

Answer (score 1):

your field vars are the elements you need to get the values of the fields to check 
the elements cannot be null

```
 var field1 = document.getElementById("englishid").value;
  var field2 = document.getElementById("mathid").value;
  var field3 = document.getElementById("computerid").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could tweak that `GradeCal` function a little bit and make it more extensible simply by using an array for field names to be processed and some basic array methods.

```
function GradeCal(){

    let result=[];
    let fields=[ 'english', 'math', 'computer' ];
    let out=document.getElementById('markid');

    fields.forEach( ( id, i )=>{
        let field=document.querySelector( 'input[name="'+id+'"]' );
        if( field && !isNaN( field.value ) && field.value!='' )result.push( parseFloat( field.value ) );
        else alert( 'Please enter a number for '+id )
    });

    if( result.length === fields.length ) {
        out.innerHTML = result.reduce(( a,v )=>{ return a + v } ) / fields.length;
    } else {
        out.innerHTML='Error';
    }
}
```

```js
function GradeCal(){

let result=[];
let fields=[ 'english', 'math', 'computer' ];
let out=document.getElementById('markid');

fields.forEach( ( id, i )=>{
 let field=document.querySelector( 'input[name="'+id+'"]' );
 if( field && !isNaN( field.value ) && field.value!='' )result.push( parseFloat( field.value ) );
 else alert( 'Please enter a number for '+id )
});

if( result.length === fields.length ) {
 out.innerHTML = result.reduce(( a,v )=>{ return a + v } ) / fields.length;
} else {
 out.innerHTML='Error';
}
}
```

```html
<h2>Grade Book Calculator</h2>
<h4> Welcome to Grade Book Calculator </h4>
<form id="my form">
  <table>
 <tr>
   <td>Student ID:</td>
   <td> <input id="studentid" value="bc180200783" oninvalid="alert(Please Enter Student ID)" type="text" place holder="Enter your VU ID" required="required" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>Name:</td>
   <td> <input id="nameid" value="Hina" oninvalid="alert(Please Enter Name)" type="text" required="required" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>Father Name:</td>
   <td> <input id="fathernameid" value="Zafar" oninvalid="alert(Please Enter Father Name)" type="text" required="required" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>CNIC:</td>
   <td> <input id="cnicid" pattern="^[0-9+][5]-[0-9+][7]-[0-9][1]$" value="33100-1100321-5" oninvalid="alert(Please Enter CNIC)" required="required" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>English:</td>
   <td> <input id="englishid" oninvalid="alert(Please Enter English Marks)" name="english" required="required" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>Math:</td>
   <td> <input id="mathid" oninvalid="alert(Please Enter Math Marks)" name="math" required="required" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>Computer:</td>
   <td> <input id="computerid" oninvalid="alert(Please Enter Computer Marks)" name="computer" required="required" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>Average Marks:</td>
   <td> <output type="number" id="markid"> </output>
   </td>
 </tr>


 <tr>
   <td> <button type="button" onClick="GradeCal()"> Grade Book </button>
  <button type="reset"> Reset</button></td>
 </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like the below code.

```js
function GradeCal() {
  var field1 = document.getElementById("englishid").value;
  var field2 = document.getElementById("mathid").value;
  var field3 = document.getElementById("computerid").value;
  var result;

  if (field1 === NULL || field2 === NULL || field3 === NULL) {
    alert("Please enter number");
  } else {
    result = (parseFloat(field1) + parseFloat(field2) + parseFloat(field3)) / 3;
    document.getElementById("markid").innerHTML = +result;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <title>It430
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <h2>Grade Book Calculator</h2>
    <h4> Welcome to Grade Book Calculator </h4>
    <form id="my form">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Student ID:</td>
          <td> <input id="studentid" value="bc180200783" oninvalid="alert(Please Enter Student ID)" type="text" place holder="Enter your VU ID" required="required" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Name:</td>
          <td> <input id="nameid" value="Hina" oninvalid="alert(Please Enter Name)" type="text" required="required" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Father Name:</td>
          <td> <input id="fathernameid" value="Zafar" oninvalid="alert(Please Enter Father Name)" type="text" required="required" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>CNIC:</td>
          <td> <input id="cnicid" pattern="^[0-9+][5]-[0-9+][7]-[0-9][1]$" value="33100-1100321-5" oninvalid="alert(Please Enter CNIC)" required="required" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>English:</td>
          <td> <input id="englishid" oninvalid="alert(Please Enter English Marks)" name="english" required="required" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Math:</td>
          <td> <input id="mathid" oninvalid="alert(Please Enter Math Marks)" name="math" required="required" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Computer:</td>
          <td> <input id="computerid" oninvalid="alert(Please Enter Computer Marks)" name="computer" required="required" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Average Marks:</td>
          <td> <output type="number" id="markid"> </output>
          </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
          <td> <button type="button" onClick="GradeCal()"> Grade Book </button>
            <button type="reset"> Reset</button></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </center>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There is no `NULL` in javascript.

Comment: You need to get the `value` from the input. (Also, if nothing is entered in the input, it will be an empty string and not `null`)

Comment: @AkshayBande there is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures

Comment: @RuudVerhoef Its `null` not `NULL` JS keywords are case sensitive.

Comment: Answers that go like "You can try the below code" and the like are usually really bad answers, despite presenting working code, which here isn't even the case. `null` is **never** the value of an `input`.

Comment: ...and you've made it even worse. I strongly suggest you delete your answer.

Comment: its not displaying the alert message if any of the field is empty

Comment: @noora  it's displaying alert messages when a condition is true.